# what design pattern should i use to let the user decide the order that methods will be performed by

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a class in which the `Start()` method calls many different methods in certain order.
Each method can be called multiple times.
There is a need to change this class in such way that in run-time the order of the methods will be defined and then the `Start()` method will run the methods in the defined order.
What would be the best design pattern to use to achive this goal in c# ?

pseudo code example of the current implementation which i wish to change:

```
class Executer
{
   public Executer() { InitializeOrderOfMethodsBasedOnUserInput(); }

   public void Start()
   {
      /* some code here */
      
      PerformA();
      PerformC("C", 0);
      PerformA();
      PerformB(1);
      PerformB(9);
      PerformD();
   }

   private void PerformA() {}
   private void PerformB(int b) {}
   private bool PerformC(string c, int x) {}
   private void PerformD() {}
}
```

Comment: you object has to have a property for 'order' which can be set

Comment: so you have a wrapper object that contains the operations list and an order property. each operation wil need a number representing the order it has been allocated.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). Not only can you have user specify order of operations, they can also only pick any number of operations they need.